# Interprocess communication between XCode (Objective C) and C program

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, xcode7

I am working on a OS X desktop application comprising two separate services.  The first, implemented in **C**, collects data in the background and relays them to the second, a UI implemented in **Objective C**.  After updating, the UI responds to the C program with an acknowledgment, thus there is two-way communication between the programs.

I presently use TCP sockets for the inter-process communication, and it works, but sometimes messages across the socket connection are delayed by up to 45 seconds.  Is there an alternative mechanism that would provide high-speed, minimal-latency between communication between my `C` and `Objective C` programs?

I am using XCode.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "better".  There are certainly arguments in favor of unix domain sockets, shared memory, pipes, etc. What features do you care about?  (That is, what's the metric by which you measure one method to be "better" than another?)

Comment: I want something like notifier.A notifier that works on  cross platform software.Whenever some change occur in C service i am sending it to UI where objective C recieves it. I am doing this using sockets.

Comment: @syammala, that really doesn't speak to which characteristics of the IPC mechanism are important to you for judging whether one is better than another.  If I understand you correctly then what you already have works, so are you dissatisfied with it in some way?

Comment: You don't need Xcode to write ObjC.   There is no such thing as code being written "in Xcode" as if "Xcode" were a language.

Comment: @bbum yeah i do know it, Xcode is an IDE. I am just telling that i am building an application by combining two services. One that is build from Xcode using objective C and other is a C binary

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah it works. But due to socket programming , some times their is a chance of delay in server-client communication(30 -45 sec). I want more reliable and speed communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before swapping out your mostly-working implementation for something completely different, it would be worth trying to tweak it it get rid of the unwanted delay.  Doing that might be as simple as modifying the socket options via `setsockopt()`.  In particular, it sounds like you might benefit from disabling [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) on the sockets involved, by setting the `TCP_NODELAY` option.  This sample code for doing so is copied, with minor modifications, from http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.16.shtml:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int flag = 1;
int result = setsockopt(sock,            /* socket affected */
                        IPPROTO_TCP,     /* set option at TCP level */
                        TCP_NODELAY,     /* name of option */
                        &flag,  
                        sizeof(int));    /* length of option value */
if (result < 0)
   ... handle the error ...
```

The next least disruptive option to try would be to switch to Unix-domain sockets (`AF_UNIX`) instead of TCP sockets.  Indeed, this is an overall better choice than TCP for communication between two processes that are guaranteed always to run on the same host, and it's still a socket interface.

There are other alternatives you could consider, such as pipes (one for each direction), message queues, and several variations on shared-memory approaches, but given your starting point, I wouldn't even consider any of those without first ruling out the socket-based alternatives.

Comment: Thank you.. Your help is much appreciated